# Publish/subscribe software to handle at least 10k requests/sec and 10k simultaneous connection

Tags: android, node.js, geo-location, distributed, nginx

I am on the verge to start making a "Large distributed application", but i'm struggling to decide what software is the most adequate to do so.

**My needs:**
A publish/subscribe application, which depending on user's preferences (subscriptions), will be updating him of new publications around him when he walks.

**Useful Information:**
**Getting user's position** is mandatory, and would be achieved via an android application that communicate with the server via an API.

**Question:**

I plan to be able to handle at least **10k requests/sec** and **10k simultaneous connection** or more. What Technologies can help me doing this?

**Reference:** The idea came to me, after reading this paper, in which, the authors used both scala language and Akka framework to achieve pretty good results.
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8069070

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, those all are my concerns and it would be helpful if you could guide me where to ask this question. Feel free to delete it afterward.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: I edited too. You can still find past versions in the question's history.